# Mongodb Typescript Driver not returning instances of a class

Tags: typescript, mongodb

Why even typed collections and methods mongodb driver not returning a instance of type object?

```js
const db = {
    Users: Collection<User> // receives mongoClient.db('xx').getCollection<User>('users')
}
```

```js
const user = await db.Users.findOne<User>({ username: 'test@test.com' });
console.log(user instanceof User); // false
```

```js
class User {
   username!: string
   myMethod():string { // can't be called from returning object
       // do something
   }
}
```